# Automatic Windows Services disabling by SYSTEM user account

Tags: service

I'm trying to enable "Performance Logs & Alerts" in services.msc and every time I set it to automatic or even manual and then start the service, after 15 minutes or so it will automatically disable itself by a "SYSTEM" user account according to the Event Viewer.

I just want to assign auto-performance counters (perfmon) on this server.  I'm using Windows Server Datacenter 2008.

Any tips on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Did you create a data collector set in the Reliability and Performance Monitor?  Once you create a User Defined data collector set and start it up to collect the pefmon stats it will start the service automatically (unless you have the service disabled).

Comment: Yes I've already configured the data collector set in PerfMon.  The trouble i'm having is the automatic service disabling of "Performance Logs & Alerts".  After 15 minutes or so after enabling the service, it will become disabled by SYSTEM user according to event viewer log.

Comment: You might want to amend your question and post the entry from the event viewer log where the SYSTEM account is disabling the service.  It's strange to see that it's actually disabling the service.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and help but it's solved now :)

Answer (score 1):

the performance log and alerts service is for use by perfmon.  Starting it will not record any counters.  On 2008 run perfmon and choose the link for "schedule and manage data" on the learn more pane for detailed instructions on how to create a data collector set.

Comment: Yes, I've already configured the data collector with set schedules to be collecting data on every hour.  The trouble I'm having is the automatic service disabling of "Performance Logs & Alerts".  After 15 minutes or so after enabling the service, it will become disabled by SYSTEM user according to event viewer log.

Comment: so ON THE HOUR that service should start, then shutdown.  By default that service should be sset to manual  startup and log on as local system.  It should be shtting itself down if there is nothing for it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I've figured it out.  Apparently there is a conflicting setting under "Stop Condition" tab.  I've set the capture seconds too low for it to have SYSTEM acct to automatically disable the Performance Log service.

It's funny how when you set a schedule to capture every hour, you would think it would enable the service itself, capture data, and close the service.  It's actually capture one data set, shutdown service after X threshold by SYSTEM acct, and never run schedule again.  Oh silly MSFT..